# Getting callback from AJAX in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my index.html.erb I have a button like:

```
<%= button_to 'Test', question_path, :remote => true, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
```

This triggers a method in my controller, which asks a server for a simple string value, and the method succesfully gets an answer back. This was verified by `puts question.gets`.

I want to pass that answer back to index.html.erb and show it in a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

create an `app/views/questions/show.js.erb` and add the js code you need here.

```
# controller
def show
  @question = ... # fetch question
end

# show.js.erb
$('#div_id').text('<%= escape_javascript @question.gets %>');
```